# Shell scripting basic

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, instance

I am new to shell and need help. What the easiest way I can script based on the command result do this else do that.

Basically I want to check the status of the instance, if its off turn it on, else do nothing

I have commands to get the instance status or grep based on the list.

Comment: Please be more specific by what you mean. Is the "status of the instance" the state of a running process? What command are you using to get the status? Are you using bash?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're scripting in Bash, as it's the most common shell by default on Linux.

You can write a script by basically writing shell commands one after another. You can write if-else structures and cycles too, they're constructed of special shell commands. You can find a pretty good summary on syntax here: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/bash/

Anyway, you need these things:

You can **load the output of a command into a variable** like `myVariable=$(ls -la)`. Even `myVariable=$(ls -la | grep "something")` works. Later, you can access your variable like `$myVariable`.

If the status you want to read is really the return value of a program rather than its output, you could use the special **variable `$?` which holds the return value** of the last executed command. You can read up on special variables [here](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/shellvars#special_parameters_and_shell_variables).

An **if-else structure** looks like this:

```sh
if [ "$Name" = "Daniya" ] || [ "$Name" = "Zach" ]
then
    echo "This will run if $Name is Daniya OR Zach."
fi
```

Comment: awesome . Thank you this will help. I should be able to create something with this idea

Answer (score 0):

Here is an shell script example using `if-else` structure to verify status of Oracle Database. If it's down, starting it and if it's running does nothing:

```
check_stat='ps -ef|grep ${ORACLE_SID}|grep pmon|wc -l';
oracle_num='expr $check_stat'
if [ $oracle_num -lt 1 ]
then
    $ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Thank you Henique.

Comment: Hi @Henique , Isnt this line check_stat='ps -ef|grep ${ORACLE_SID}|grep pmon|wc -l'; takes whole command as string? It does for me atleast?